# Add <hr> after every two items in Angular 2 *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following ngFor code which loop through an Object.

```
<a *ngFor="let pictures of picturesData" href="">
  <img [src]="pictures.img" alt="">
</a>
```

I want to display an `<hr>` after every 2 `<a>` tags (but not after the last 2) in order to get an output something similar to the following:

```
<a href=""><img /></a>
<a href=""><img /></a>

<hr>

<a href=""><img /></a>
<a href=""><img /></a>

<hr>

<a href=""><img /></a>
<a href=""><img /></a>
```

How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ngFor`'s `odd` property and [ng-container](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#group-sibling-elements-with-lt-ng-container-gt-)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pictures of picturesData; let odd=odd">
  <a href="">
    <img [src]="pictures.img" alt="">
  </a>
  <hr *ngIf='odd'>
</ng-container>
```